# MySQL ORDER BY Alphanumeric values, first all integers, then all alphas

Tags: mysql

searched around awhile for a solution to this problem, but no answer yet.

Have a column of alphanumeric model ID numbers to populate an index in a certain order. Two different attempts with the order they produced:

```
ORDER BY Model_ID ASC
1278-8
211E
350-50
996
3800P
AP23
AP263
AP26M
JA042


ORDER BY CAST(Model_ID AS UNSIGNED), Model_ID
AP23
AP263
AP26M
JA042
211E
350-50
996
1278-8
3800P
```

However, I need to have it sorted like so, with all of the integer-starting numbers exhausted first:

```
211E
350-50
996
1278-8
3800P
AP23
AP263
AP26M
JA042
```

Help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sample data, this will get the desired order:

```
ORDER BY Model_ID+0=0, Model_ID+0, Model_ID ASC
```

Let's unpack that a bit.

The expression `Model_ID+0` evaluates Model_ID in a numeric context, by adding zero to it. Basically, MySQL gets whatever leading characters that can be converted to a number, and disregards the rest. For values that can't be interpreted as a number, MySQL returns 0.

The first expression checks if the numeric value is zero, so those will be sorted last. (MySQL returns numeric value of 1 for boolean TRUE, 0 for FALSE.)

The second expression gets the non-zero values sorted in numeric order.

NOTE: these expressions "work" for the sample data; the edge case is values that have leading zeros as the numeric value, e.g. '000ABC' will be sorted after all the other "numeric" values. And MySQL doesn't stop at just the integer portion, if there's a dot character, that can be interpreted as a decimal point.

You can see the values of the expressions (for testing), by including them in the SELECT list, e.g.

```
SELECT Model_ID+0=0, Model_ID+0, ...
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks not only for the simple solution, but also the explanation! Wonderful.

Comment: @user3569292: This isn't an entirely foolproof solution, the "edge" cases are leading zeros evaluating to numeric value of zero, and dot characters interpreted as decimal points (not just the integer portion), etc.

Comment: But leading 0s only evaluate as 0s if followed by non-numeric!

Comment: I understand spencer. Fortunately, none of the model ID's used at my company employ leading zeroes or special characters besides hyphens. Your solution is all I need for my purpose. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table (model_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('1278-8'),
 ('211E'),
 ('350-50'),
 ('996'),
 ('3800P'),
 ('AP23'),
 ('AP263'),
 ('AP26M'),
 ('JA042');

 SELECT model_id FROM my_table ORDER BY model_id + 0 = 0,model_id + 0;
 +----------+
 | model_id |
 +----------+
 | 211E     |
 | 350-50   |
 | 996      |
 | 1278-8   |
 | 3800P    |
 | AP23     |
 | AP263    |
 | AP26M    |
 | JA042    |
 +----------+
```